# Publish WPF/.NET application with sounds files

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, audio

I am working on a WPF (.Net Core 6) project which I publish as **Self-Contained** and as **Single file**, hence I get a single runnable executable (.exe) as my published application. The WPF application will play a sound (a .wav file) on a keypress event. This works in VS2022 debug mode as the sound files are located in the .Net project in the folder `/Resources/SoundFile.wav`.

However, the application crashes when running the published executable because the path to the sound file is incorrect. How do I configure the correct relative path to the sound files when running from the **Self-Contained** and **Single file** executable?

This is what the code looks like now:

```
PlaySoundFile(GetSoundFilePath("../../../Resources/SoundFile.wav"));
```

```
        private void PlaySoundFile(string soundPath)
        {
            SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(GetSoundFilePath(soundPath));
            soundPlayer.Load();
            soundPlayer.Play();
        }

        private string GetSoundFilePath(string soundPath)
        {
            Assembly? assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            string? baseDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location);
            return new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(baseDir, soundPath)).FullName;
        }
```

I have tried to find what the path to the sound file could be when running the executable, as I believe it could be to some Temp folder created at run-time and deleted once the WPF application is closed. But without success so far.

Comment: Just to check, are the wave files all set as a resource and to "copy if newer"? The output should still be a single file but unless the properties are set this way they are not being published out.

Comment: Where is `SoundFile.wav` supposed to be located when you deploy the application? You need to decide this before you can implement your application to find it. The application itself is obviously not self-contained in a single `.exe` if it relies on another `wav` file being present somewhere. Do you want to embed the `.wav` file into the `.exe` or how and where do you intend to deploy it alongside the `.exe`?

Comment: Yes, I want to embed the .wav file into the self-contained and single file .exe. I want to be able to give the single file .exe to another person and when they run it out of the box and press the button, it should play the sound.

Answer (score 0):

Consider NOT passing in a path but the stream to the data, then you can load it either into memory and stream from there or get the resource as stream. Turn it into an embedded resource.